# How to send https request with client certificate using Python programming language

Tags: python, python-2.7, authentication, ssl, jks

I have two jks files truststore.jks and keystore.jks that I use when sending REST request with java based client , now I want to use Python but I didn't find a way to use them to authenticate so How can I use them in Python ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't provide much of info (e.g. what you tried before), so my answer will be not precise.

I think what you are looking for is [`urllib2.urlopen()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen) (probably using [`Request`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.Request) object to tune up request properties), note SSL-related function parameters. But first you'll probably need to convert jks files to format accepted by Python (I guess it's OpenSSL format).